# Keep the old referrer after failed login

Tags: redirect, login, wp-redirect

I have the following problem that I couldn't find any solution for.

I have a simple custom login page, which I've managed to set up, so it redirects to the referred URL the user came from.
The problem is, when user fails to authenticate - yes, s/he still stays on the same custom page, but the original referrer is lost, and now is replaced with the same custom-login page the user is currently on.

In short, what I want to achieve is:

1. User clicks the link to the document and sees the info that he has to login first to see it.
2. User goes to the login page, with HTTP_REFERRER set properly to the page he came from.
3. User types wrong password and is kept on the same login page, **with the original HTTP_REFERRER** so that after he types in the correct password, he will be redirected to the original page **he came from**, instead of seeing the empty login page.

I've managed to do it with the proper login process, but it looks way harder when the page refreshes and loses its original referrer...

Comment: Does that actually work in the success case? It sounds like you're submitting the page in 2->3 so the code that handles that form post won't have the original referrer from 1->2.

Comment: What you probably want to do is to save the referrer in a hidden form field on 2, or add it as a query parameter to post back to when you process the login, or just add the referrer as a query parameter on the login page URL (how WordPress's own login works). Then you can preserve that value on the login failure case.